# ubuntu phone aquaris e4.5 dual boot

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, smartphone

I bought the ubuntu phone aquaris e4.5 (ubuntu edition).

Is there a way to dual-boot that device with android ?

Any tips are more than welcome.

Best regards,
Oleg

Comment: Interesting question!!! What about E5-HD? Dual boot?

Comment: no answers so far.